# Criando data set para sklearn com dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho a seguinte situação

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,8,6,1],'B':[2,6,9,3,2]})
y = pd.DataFrame({'C':[8,6,3,6,1]})
```

Como eu faço pra que isso aconteça?

```
LogisticRegression( ).fit(x, y)
```

tenho a seguinte resposta:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: array([8,6,3,6,1]) #valores do y
```

Qual a forma correta??

Comment: não entendo muito de python, mas regressão logística é usada p/ classificação. Então chutaria que o y no seu caso não deveria ser do tipo numérico...

Comment: Nooosa... eu achando que o sklearn faria o mesmo que o Proj.log (logest) do excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O logistic regression do sklearn é usado para classificação e implementa [esse método](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regress%C3%A3o_log%C3%ADstica) que é capaz de distinguir entre duas classes diferentes(eg.: doente  e saudável), para que ele funcione a chamada do método fit() recebe dois parâmetros, o primeiro são as suas "observações" em forma de uma matrix e o segundo um vetor com as classes correspondentes a cada uma das observações, no seu caso, acredito que o problema é que você está passando um DataFrame como segundo parâmetro, talvez você queira tentar isso `LogisticRegression().fit(x, y.C)`.

Note que esse método é semelhante ao Proj.log(logest) do Excel que aproxima uma curva da forma y=b*(m1^x1)*(m2^x2)...(mn^xn).Enquanto a  regressão logística aproxima uma curva [desta forma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_log%C3%ADstica).